# Build keycloak docker hub image in openshift from new-app command

Tags: postgresql, docker, openshift, keycloak

I'm trying to deploy the Keycloak image [Keycloak HA Postgres](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak-ha-postgres/) in openshift 3.6. As precondition I have to say I can't run docker on my local machine, so I have to create the image from oc new-app command.

When I try to call

```
 oc new-app jboss/keycloak-ha-postgres
```

then the image is downloaded but I have errors when the server starts:

```
Cannot start embedded server: Failed to instantiate class "org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler" for handler "FILE": java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/log/server.log (Permission denied)
Cannot start embedded server: Failed to instantiate class "org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler" for handler "FILE": java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/log/server.log (Permission denied)
```

And also which environment variable (names) I have to set up for connecting to my postgres?

Answer (score 0):

So at the end I could figure out what the problem was. With the help of the command:

```
oc status -v
```

I saw the following error/warning:

```
Current security policy prevents your containers from being run as the root user. Some images
may fail expecting to be able to change ownership or permissions on directories. Your admin
can grant you access to run containers that need to run as the root user with this command:

oadm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid -n keycloak-test -z keycloak
```

So I added a service account user:

```
oc create sa keycloak
```

and contacted my System administrator that has to grant permissions to the keycloak serviceAccount user.

At least I had to to add to the deploymentConfig the serviceAccount

```
spec:
   ....
   template:
   .....
   spec:
       containers:
       ......
       serviceAccount: keycloak
       serviceAccountName: keycloak
```

So that's all.

I add a little hint for them that have to add the new adminUser at beginning.
You have to add two environment variables **KEYCLOAK_USER** and **KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD**. 
The other env variables that I set were: **POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR**, **POSTGRES_PASSWORD**, **POSTGRES_USER** and **POSTGRES_DATABASE**.

Comment: I'm trying the same and I've granted the "edit"-role to the service account. Adding the service account to my configuration-YAML doesn't solve the problem though, the logmanager still can not create logs. Do you know which permissions were granted to your service account for keycloak?

Comment: Hi, when I perform a oc describe policybinding I se that the serviceaccount is under the system:image-pullers. I hope this can help you

Comment: This doesn't do it for me, sadly. I will try and ask my cluster admin to run the command the console is giving, but it might not be available in OpenShift Online.