# How to disable Jboss PeriodicRotatingFileHandler in KeyCloak-Server-Distribution

Tags: logging, jboss, openshift, wildfly, keycloak

**Background**
The plan is to deploy a current version of KeyCloak for our business. We use OpenShift Online to host similar services. Pods (containers) in OpenShift-Online do not have root privileges, which means that the standard implementation of [jboss-dockerfiles/keycloak](https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/keycloak/tree/master/server) fails on startup, trying to write a logfile without permission to write.
A solution would be to give the pod permissions to write, [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47796208/build-keycloak-docker-hub-image-in-openshift-from-new-app-command/47864928?noredirect=1#comment84042383_47864928). This is however is not possible in OpenShift Online because we do not own the cluster, only the project we work in.

**The actual problem**
The idea was to disable the relevant logging configuration in Jboss running KeyCloak, so that the logs are not written to a file. Since they are written to the console, the logs are still collected by OpenShift, so we do not need the logging to a file anyways.

After looking into how keycloak/keycloak and jboss-dockerfiles/keycloak work together, I found relevant configuration lines in the servers standalone.xml file. I added the following line to the project's Dockerfile to remove the PeriodicRotatingFileHandler from the server:

```
    sed -i -e '/<periodic-rotating-file-handler/,/<\/periodic-rotating-file-handler>/d' /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml
```

This does work - when I enter the containers filesystem after creation using `docker run --rm -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash <imageId>` and check the standalone.xml, the relevant lines configuring a PeriodicRotatingFileHandler as "FILE" are gone.

When I start the new container in OpenShift Online, the deployment still fails, however, because the server still tries to start up the logger:

```
Cannot start embedded server: Failed to instantiate class "org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler" for handler "FILE": java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/log/server.log (Permission denied) 
[...]  
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to instantiate class "org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler" for handler "FILE"
```

Why is the server still starting up that logger, despite it not being declared in standalone.xml anymore? Is there a second configuration file that is used instead? Is there a way to force an overwrite for that handler?

Comment: The handler would also have to be removed from the root-logger as well.

Comment: Why not use ``jboss/keycloak-openshift`` image if KeyCloak image is the issue. See https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/keycloak/tree/master/server-openshift

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I will look into it; if you know how, feel free to leave an answer!

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton that image had PeriodicRotatingFileHandler enabled too last time I tried. It works for OpenShift installations where we could use oadm, but in OpenShift Online, we do not have cluster administration permissions.

Comment: I know ``jboss/keycloak-openshift`` works in Online as I use it there. Are you saying it doesn't start, or just that the logs aren't collected.

Comment: The specific version I use is ``jboss/keycloak-openshift:4.0.0.Final``.

Comment: I just looked into it and tried jboss/keycloak-openshift:4.2.1.Final, but it fails with `/usr/bin/openshift-entrypoint.sh: line 3: exec: -b: invalid option` ; I assumed it's because the Dockerfile tries to run the chown and chmod commands and it doesn't work because this would require permissions too, but if it works for you I'll try to find the source of that problem for now

Comment: The problem is that the implementation of jboss/keycloak-openshift expects an external database to be run in a container, being linked with the keycloak-container; but we run our database using a database service outside of OpenShift, so we need an image that supports DB-configuration via an endpoint

Comment: I don't use a container for the database where rely on linking, I set the environment variables to specify the database location. I do have the database in a separate deployment in same project, but using that method the database could just as easily be outside of OpenShift, just set hostname in ``DB_ADDR`` environment variable. https://github.com/jupyter-on-openshift/poc-hub-keycloak-auth/blob/master/templates/jupyterhub.json#L953

Comment: that's weird then... why does the image fail then if I take it straight from jboss/keycloak-openshift:4.2.1.Final... currently also trying to just run the same chown & chmod commands on a customized image, but still getting the permission errors

Answer (score 1):

**Not really an answer to the original question** regarding the logger, but a workaround:
Using the image [jboss/keycloak-openshift](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak-openshift/) ([GitHub](https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/keycloak/tree/master/server-openshift)), KeyCloak can be run on OpenShift Online without further configuration of the logging. There are some additional configurations that need to be done:

1. Set PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true in the environment variables of the deployment to make KeyCloak listen to forward-headers (since KeyCloak 4.0.0)
2. Set `docker run` args according to the images Dockerfile in the deployments .yaml:

[...]
     containers:
        - args:
        - start-keycloak.sh
        - '-b 0.0.0.0'
[...]